# Error on running database script

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I generate script of my database (types of data to script = schema and data) from SQL Server 2008 R2 and run this script in SQL Server 2005, it shows me these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '100'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 6, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY'.
>
> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format'.

at State 1, Line 1

```
ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

at State 6, Line 1

```
ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
```

at State 62, Line 1

```
EXEC sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format N'MYDATABASE', N'ON'
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I've also change COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100 (version 2008) to COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90 (version 2005) , but it doesn't work too .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

SQL Server 2005 doesn't have this command yet - new feature of SQL Server 2008.

You need to use this instead:

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel AdventureWorks, 90;
```

Level 90 = SQL Server 2005 - that'll work; level 100 is SQL Server 2008 which will **not** work in SQL Server 2005 obviuosly.....

```
ALTER DATABASE [MYDATABASE] SET HONOR_BROKER_PRIORITY OFF
EXEC sys.sp_db_vardecimal_storage_format N'MYDATABASE', N'ON'
```

Those are both **new features** in SQL Server 2008 or newer and don't have any equivalent in SQL Server 2005. The `vardecimal` storage format isn't supported (nor needed) in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @zey: well, since those features **aren't present** in SQL Server 2005 - yes, there's no other way, really. You should check out the `Generate script` wizard - it has a setting that allows you to define which **version** of SQL Server to generate the script for. Try to set that to **2005** and see what the result would be

Comment: Fortunately marc_s , it has `Script for Server Version` options which can change script version to 2005 :)